# Split is undefined in JavaScript function (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Objective:** To create a function, which takes the icon URL as an argument and splits it to return the last part of the URL, which is expected to be an icon name. The main Icon URL is coming from an Object. Which is a string.

**What is happening:** When I log the value of the icon URL It is correct but when I pass it inside the function it becomes undefined.

Code:

```js
const generateIconUrl = code => {
   const lastItem = code.split("/").pop();

   let currentHour = moment().format("HH");
   let dayOrNight;

   if (currentHour >= 3 && currentHour < 12) {
      dayOrNight = "day";
   } else if (currentHour >= 20 && currentHour < 3) {
      dayOrNight = "night";
   }

   const iconBaseUrl = `/weatherIcons/${dayOrNight}/`;
   const iconUrl = iconBaseUrl + lastItem.slice(0, 3);

   return iconUrl;
};
```

**How am I calling this function:**

```js
const WeatherIcon = data.current.condition.icon;

<img className="object-cover w-44" src={generateIconUrl(WeatherIcon)} alt="weather" />
```

**Here is what fixed it**

```
   const generateIconUrl = code => {
      let currentHour = moment().format("HH");
      let dayOrNight;

      if (currentHour >= 3 && currentHour < 12) {
         dayOrNight = "day";
      } else if (currentHour >= 20 && currentHour < 3) {
         dayOrNight = "night";
      }

      const iconBaseUrl = `/weatherIcons/${dayOrNight}/${code.split("/").pop().slice(0, 3)}.svg`;

      return iconBaseUrl;
   };
```

Comment: Where and how do you pass anything into this function…?

Comment: @deceze Like this
`<img className="object-cover w-44" src={generateIconUrl(someIconUrl)} alt="weather" />`

Comment: ```if (currentHour >= 3 && currentHour < 12) {
      dayOrNight = "day";
   } else if (currentHour >= 20 && currentHour < 3) {
      dayOrNight = "night";
   }```

Comment: And how are you sure `WeatherIcon` is set to what you think it is set…?

Comment: @deceze I checked it twice by logging it to the console. It returns this ```//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png```

Comment: That may happen with very different timing than it's happening in the actual code. Please present a *complete, reproducible sample* that we can follow and debug.

Comment: alright I fixed it

Comment: here is the solution